# ASP.NET Core Web API HttpPost with charset1252

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to configure my WebAPI to accept a charset other than UTF-8. I have added the encoding to the JsonInputFormatter as follows:

```
 Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

        services.AddMvc(options => options.InputFormatters.OfType<JsonInputFormatter>().First().SupportedEncodings.Add(
            enc1252));
```

I specify the following HttpHeader:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=windows-1252
```

However, I can only return 415 Unsupported Media Type. 
If I update the header to utf-8 or unicode then this will work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that

> options.InputFormatters.OfType().First

Was picking up the JsonPatchInputFormatter. Updated to add the encoding to both JsonInputFormatter and JsonInputPatchFormatter and this resolved the issue

Comment: If that solves your problem then you can accept your own answer as the corrected answer :)